# Shortest distance between a point and a line segment

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, distance, line-segment

I need a basic function to find the shortest distance between a point and a line segment.  Feel free to write the solution in any language you want; I can translate it into what I'm using (Javascript).

EDIT: My line segment is defined by two endpoints. So my line segment `AB` is defined by the two points `A (x1,y1)` and `B (x2,y2)`.  I'm trying to find the distance between this line segment and a point `C (x3,y3)`.  My geometry skills are rusty, so the examples I've seen are confusing, I'm sorry to admit.

Comment: I don't know how you're representing lines and points, but [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) is all the mathematics you need to get started. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Is the answer of this questions can be fixed/changed ? The current is not for the question (segment), but for a line.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski: that link is dead, but I've found a copy: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/

Comment: Had to look for this myself & stumbled upon this from Google -- if anyone is looking for an implementation & can go with Python, [Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) has this. You're looking for the `LineString` class for the path.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: that link is dead too, but this similar link works: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Comment: If someone's looking for distance between a point and a line, not a point and a line SEGMENT, check this link: https://gist.github.com/rhyolight/2846020

Comment: The link above is dead. Here's pseudo-code and c++ sample, explained and derived as detailed as a textbook,  http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/

Answer (score 522, accepted):

<strike>Eli, the code you've settled on is incorrect. A point near the line on which the segment lies but far off one end of the segment would be incorrectly judged near the segment.</strike> *Update: The incorrect answer mentioned is no longer the accepted one.*

Here's some correct code, in C++. It presumes a class 2D-vector `class vec2 {float x,y;}`, essentially, with operators to add, subract, scale, etc, and a distance and dot product function (i.e. `x1 x2 + y1 y2`).

```c++
float minimum_distance(vec2 v, vec2 w, vec2 p) {
  // Return minimum distance between line segment vw and point p
  const float l2 = length_squared(v, w);  // i.e. |w-v|^2 -  avoid a sqrt
  if (l2 == 0.0) return distance(p, v);   // v == w case
  // Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as v + t (w - v).
  // We find projection of point p onto the line. 
  // It falls where t = [(p-v) . (w-v)] / |w-v|^2
  // We clamp t from [0,1] to handle points outside the segment vw.
  const float t = max(0, min(1, dot(p - v, w - v) / l2));
  const vec2 projection = v + t * (w - v);  // Projection falls on the segment
  return distance(p, projection);
}
```

EDIT: I needed a Javascript implementation, so here it is, with no dependencies (or comments, but it's a direct port of the above). Points are represented as objects with `x` and `y` attributes.

```javascript
function sqr(x) { return x * x }
function dist2(v, w) { return sqr(v.x - w.x) + sqr(v.y - w.y) }
function distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w) {
  var l2 = dist2(v, w);
  if (l2 == 0) return dist2(p, v);
  var t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
  t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t));
  return dist2(p, { x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x),
                    y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y) });
}
function distToSegment(p, v, w) { return Math.sqrt(distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w)); }
```

EDIT 2: I needed a Java version, but more important, I needed it in 3d instead of 2d.

```java
float dist_to_segment_squared(float px, float py, float pz, float lx1, float ly1, float lz1, float lx2, float ly2, float lz2) {
  float line_dist = dist_sq(lx1, ly1, lz1, lx2, ly2, lz2);
  if (line_dist == 0) return dist_sq(px, py, pz, lx1, ly1, lz1);
  float t = ((px - lx1) * (lx2 - lx1) + (py - ly1) * (ly2 - ly1) + (pz - lz1) * (lz2 - lz1)) / line_dist;
  t = constrain(t, 0, 1);
  return dist_sq(px, py, pz, lx1 + t * (lx2 - lx1), ly1 + t * (ly2 - ly1), lz1 + t * (lz2 - lz1));
}
```

Here, in the function parameters, `<px,py,pz>` is the point in question and the line segment has the endpoints `<lx1,ly1,lz1>` and `<lx2,ly2,lz2>`. The function `dist_sq` (which is assumed to exist) finds the square of the distance between two points.

Comment: I've added a fleshed-out version of this as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks @Grumdrig, your javascript solution was spot on and a huge time saver. I ported your solution to Objective-C and added it below.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer shouldn't the float equality be determined by another function instead of directly ``==``?

Comment: We're really just trying to avoid a divide by zero there.

Comment: Excuse me for asking. If the distance is 0 does it mean the point has cut the line segment?

Comment: Yes, the point should be somewhere on the line segment (possibly at an endpoint) in that case.

Comment: @Grumdrig (and to the people who ported into other languages): This is a really handy, short piece of code. Have you considered making this answer into a Gist? (https://gist.github.com)

Comment: Can someone give a more descriptive definition of t and projection please?  specifically how they relate to whether the projection lands on the line segment or not?

Comment: The projection of point `p` onto a line is the point on the line closest to `p`. (And a perpendicular to the line at the projection will pass through `p`.) The number `t` is how far along the line segment from `v` to `w` that the projection falls. So if `t` is 0 the projection falls right on `v`; if it's 1, it's on `w`; if it's 0.5, for example, then it's halfway between. If `t` is less than 0 or greater than 1 it falls on the line past one end or the other of the segment. In that case the distance to the segment will be the distance to the nearer end.

Comment: How can I do this in 3d?

Comment: JS code converted to PHP: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/43571942/4577762](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43571942/4577762)

Comment: @grumdrig It looks like this function returns a positive distance if the point lies on the line segment and the numbers are small; i.e. if `p = (0.0001, 0.0)`, `v = (0.0, 0.0)`, `w = (0.004, 0.0)`, it returns `1.3552527156068805e-20` (see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qg0zerkc/). Is this a floating-point stability issue?

Comment: @urschrei That would be floating point imprecision - if you're testing for whether a point is on the line you'd want to check that the distance is less than some small value adequate to your needs, rather than equality with zero.

Comment: Let's say the line segment was 2 lat/lon points and the point was another lat/lon point, how could I get the distance returned in miles?

Comment: @RogiSolorzano That's a 3D problem (earth isn't flat) so if you want accuracy this isn't the solution for you. If you want a very rough estimate for points not too far apart there's very very roughly 60 miles per degree.

Comment: Oops - didn't notice someone had supplied a 3D version. @RogiSolorzano, you'll need to convert the lat,long coordinates into x,y,z coordinates in 3-space first.

Comment: so you are saying the last snippet is in Java, huh ?

Comment: The implementation can even be sped up by avoiding to compute the `projection`. Since the distance from `p` to line `v,w` is equal to `sqrt(|p-v|^2 - (|w-v|*t)^2)`. Thus the last 2 lines of the c++ implementation can be replaced by `return sqrt(length_squared(p, v) - l2 * (t * t));`

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/

Comment: It works but it’s inefficient. The code will do branching anyway, for min/max. When min or max clamps `t`, there’s no need to calculate the rest of the formula, you already know you need the distance between `p` and `v` or `w`.

Comment: What about the special case where one of the points is (0, 0)?

Comment: anyone has 3D implementation in python?

Comment: All these are calculating `t` with something equivalent to `dot(p - v, w - v) / l2)`, which is `t = u.v / || u ||²`. Shouldn't they be using the square root of l2? Meaning, the segment's length, IOW the magnitude of the vector w-v, and not its square.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Grumdrig Having trouble guessing what dist_sq(lx1, ly1, lz1, lx2, ly2, lz2) does. Does it find the distance between the two points (sum of sqares and then sqare root)? or does it not take a square root? I tried using the code and was getting strange results when I didnt take a square root in definitio of the dist_sq() function

Comment: @Goku It finds the square of the distance between two points. (Sum of squares of component differences.) I've added some explanation to the end of the answer.

Comment: the code in c++ is wrong, because it doesn't take into account that a point can be closer to the line than to one of the line ends. for example, taking a point directly on the line segment will return the distance from the closest segment end, instead of returning length 0

Comment: @BuyMyBeard Not so. In this case the projection onto the line segment would be the point itself and the distance would be zero. Work through a simple example.

Answer (score 224):

Here is the simplest complete code in Javascript.

x, y is your target point and x1, y1 to x2, y2 is your line segment.

UPDATED: fix for 0 length line problem from comments.

```javascript
function pDistance(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  var A = x - x1;
  var B = y - y1;
  var C = x2 - x1;
  var D = y2 - y1;

  var dot = A * C + B * D;
  var len_sq = C * C + D * D;
  var param = -1;
  if (len_sq != 0) //in case of 0 length line
      param = dot / len_sq;

  var xx, yy;

  if (param < 0) {
    xx = x1;
    yy = y1;
  }
  else if (param > 1) {
    xx = x2;
    yy = y2;
  }
  else {
    xx = x1 + param * C;
    yy = y1 + param * D;
  }

  var dx = x - xx;
  var dy = y - yy;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

[image: Image to help visualize the solution]

UPDATED: Kotlin version

```kotlin
fun getDistance(x: Double, y: Double, x1: Double, y1: Double, x2: Double, y2: Double): Double {
    val a = x - x1
    val b = y - y1
    val c = x2 - x1
    val d = y2 - y1

    val lenSq = c * c + d * d
    val param = if (lenSq != .0) { //in case of 0 length line
        val dot = a * c + b * d
        dot / lenSq
    } else {
        -1.0
    }

    val (xx, yy) = when {
        param < 0 -> x1 to y1
        param > 1 -> x2 to y2
        else -> x1 + param * c to y1 + param * d
    }

    val dx = x - xx
    val dy = y - yy
    return hypot(dx, dy)
}
```

Comment: Of all the code I've seen to solve this problem, I like this one the best. It is very clear and easy to read. The math behind it though, is a little bit mystical. What does the dot-product divided by the length squared really represent, for example?

Comment: The dot product divided by length squared gives you the projection distance from (x1, y1). This is the fraction of the line that the point (x,y) is closest to. Notice the final else clause where (xx, yy) is calculated - this the projection of the point (x,y) onto the segment (x1,y1)-(x2,y2).

Comment: Updated to fix the 0 length line problem.

Comment: The distance returned in this function is in what? Meters, Kilometers?

Comment: Meters. It is returned in meters.

Comment: I think the second condition `if (param > 1)` should be `if(param>len_sq)`. Any one?

Comment: What does it mean when the param < 0 or > 1?

Comment: Can someone who understands each step add comments or provide an explanation? I know we're calculating the projection, I'm not sure why we're diving again by the norm and why we're checking of it's < 0 or > 1 and then finally what is dx, dy? Thanks

Comment: @nevermind, let's call our point p0 and the points that define the line as p1 and p2. Then you get the vectors A = p0 - p1 and B = p2 - p1. Param is the scalar value that when multiplied to B gives you the point on the line closest to p0. If param <= 0, the closest point is p1. If param >= 1, the closest point is p1. If it's between 0 and 1, it's somewhere between p1 and p2 so we interpolate. XX and YY is then the closest point on the line segment, dx/dy is the vector from p0 to that point, and finally we return the length that vector.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/

Comment: For anyone who needs an explanation for why this code works, please see this wikipedia permalink for [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vector_projection&oldid=861961162#Vector_projection_2) and refer to the image at the beginning of the article for reference.

Comment: @Joshua it doesn't necessarily return meters. It returns the same unit that is used for the input coordinates.

Comment: @ViniBiso In case it wasn't obvious from the other comments that jokingly replied "metres", the distance is returned in whatever you put in. So if you feed in metres, it will return metres. If you feed in miles, it will return miles. If you feed in shklobmorphs, it will return shklobmorphs. Same as virtually all geometric maths.

Comment: How can I make it so that it can also work with lines that extend forever and lines that have one end that extends forever?

Comment: I think the sqrt can be avoided since we apply this for all points and use the return value

Comment: I found something odd, where two lines will have equal distance calculations for a point in fairly complex space:

    > pDistance(-79.73851776123047, 43.65549087524414, -79.7388727891, 43.6549957985, -79.7388654821, 43.6549894151);
    0.0006092173427681732
    > pDistance(-79.73851776123047, 43.65549087524414, -79.7396021293, 43.6545140287, -79.7388727891, 43.6549957985);
    0.0006092173427681732

I have to try with another approach but I don't expect the same distance to appear as often as it does.

Comment: There are numerous ways to solve this. But this is the best way,

Comment: I created a jsbin out using this solution: https://jsbin.com/luyayijesa/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 83):

This is an implementation made for FINITE LINE SEGMENTS, not infinite lines like most other functions here seem to be (that's why I made this).

[Implementation of theory by Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/).

**Python:**

```python
def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3): # x3,y3 is the point
    px = x2-x1
    py = y2-y1

    norm = px*px + py*py

    u =  ((x3 - x1) * px + (y3 - y1) * py) / float(norm)

    if u > 1:
        u = 1
    elif u < 0:
        u = 0

    x = x1 + u * px
    y = y1 + u * py

    dx = x - x3
    dy = y - y3

    # Note: If the actual distance does not matter,
    # if you only want to compare what this function
    # returns to other results of this function, you
    # can just return the squared distance instead
    # (i.e. remove the sqrt) to gain a little performance

    dist = (dx*dx + dy*dy)**.5

    return dist
```

**AS3:**

```as3
public static function segmentDistToPoint(segA:Point, segB:Point, p:Point):Number
{
    var p2:Point = new Point(segB.x - segA.x, segB.y - segA.y);
    var something:Number = p2.x*p2.x + p2.y*p2.y;
    var u:Number = ((p.x - segA.x) * p2.x + (p.y - segA.y) * p2.y) / something;

    if (u > 1)
        u = 1;
    else if (u < 0)
        u = 0;

    var x:Number = segA.x + u * p2.x;
    var y:Number = segA.y + u * p2.y;

    var dx:Number = x - p.x;
    var dy:Number = y - p.y;

    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    return dist;
}
```

**Java**

```java
private double shortestDistance(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,float x3,float y3)
    {
        float px=x2-x1;
        float py=y2-y1;
        float temp=(px*px)+(py*py);
        float u=((x3 - x1) * px + (y3 - y1) * py) / (temp);
        if(u>1){
            u=1;
        }
        else if(u<0){
            u=0;
        }
        float x = x1 + u * px;
        float y = y1 + u * py;

        float dx = x - x3;
        float dy = y - y3;
        double dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        return dist;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I tried this and it still gives me the results as if the line was extending into infinity. I've found Grumdig's answer to work, though.

Comment: In that case you're using it wrong or meaning something else with non-infinite. See an example of this code here: http://boomie.se/upload/Drawdebug.swf

Comment: Looks like a mistake in code or something, I get the same result as Frederik/

Comment: Strange. Well, in the swf example I use exactly this code (it's copy pasted), and if the behavior in that swf is what you're looking for, this is the code.

Comment: The choice of variable names is far from good (p2, something, u, ...)

Comment: I've tried the Python version of the function and found that it shows incorrect results if the parameters are integers. `distAnother(0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2)` gives 2.8284271247461903 (incorrect). `distAnother(0., 0., 4., 0., 2., 2.)` gives 2.0 (correct). Please be aware of this. I think the code can be improved to have float conversion somewhere.

Comment: @VladimirObrizan No, 2.8284 is correct. The closest point on the segment to (0,0) is (2,2), giving an answer of sqrt(8). A value of 2.0 is correct for an infinite line containing the line segment (then the closest point would be (0,4) giving an answer of sqrt(4)=2.0). Nothing to do with integers or floats.

Comment: @sean, no, 2.0 is correct. You can draw the line ((0, 0), (4, 0)) yourself , put a point at (2, 2) and see that there is no difference if the line is finite or infinite, because the closest point from (2,2) to line ((0, 0), (4, 0)) is (2, 0) and the length of ((2, 2), (2, 0)) is 2.

Comment: @VladimirObrizan I believe we are talking about two different things. I am referring to the closest point on the line between (4,0) and (2,2) from the point (0,0) which is (2,2). Of course the closest point on the line between (0,0) and (4,0) to the point (2,2) is (2,0).

Comment: @sean in the original comment dated 10 years ago example given is between ((0,0), (4, 0)) and (2,2).

Comment: As of the date of this comment, it seems that the problem with the Python version that Vladimir pointed out has been fixed. Passing integers gives the correct result of 2.0.

Comment: For a faster Python implementation see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77937862/12842085

Answer (score 23):

In my own question thread [how to calculate shortest 2D distance between a point and a line segment in all cases in C, C# / .NET 2.0 or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438244/how-to-calculate-shortest-2d-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment-in-all-c) I was asked to put a C# answer here when I find one: so here it is, modified from http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=geometry1&module=Static :

```c#
//Compute the dot product AB . BC
private double DotProduct(double[] pointA, double[] pointB, double[] pointC)
{
    double[] AB = new double[2];
    double[] BC = new double[2];
    AB[0] = pointB[0] - pointA[0];
    AB[1] = pointB[1] - pointA[1];
    BC[0] = pointC[0] - pointB[0];
    BC[1] = pointC[1] - pointB[1];
    double dot = AB[0] * BC[0] + AB[1] * BC[1];

    return dot;
}

//Compute the cross product AB x AC
private double CrossProduct(double[] pointA, double[] pointB, double[] pointC)
{
    double[] AB = new double[2];
    double[] AC = new double[2];
    AB[0] = pointB[0] - pointA[0];
    AB[1] = pointB[1] - pointA[1];
    AC[0] = pointC[0] - pointA[0];
    AC[1] = pointC[1] - pointA[1];
    double cross = AB[0] * AC[1] - AB[1] * AC[0];

    return cross;
}

//Compute the distance from A to B
double Distance(double[] pointA, double[] pointB)
{
    double d1 = pointA[0] - pointB[0];
    double d2 = pointA[1] - pointB[1];

    return Math.Sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2);
}

//Compute the distance from AB to C
//if isSegment is true, AB is a segment, not a line.
double LineToPointDistance2D(double[] pointA, double[] pointB, double[] pointC, 
    bool isSegment)
{
    double dist = CrossProduct(pointA, pointB, pointC) / Distance(pointA, pointB);
    if (isSegment)
    {
        double dot1 = DotProduct(pointA, pointB, pointC);
        if (dot1 > 0) 
            return Distance(pointB, pointC);

        double dot2 = DotProduct(pointB, pointA, pointC);
        if (dot2 > 0) 
            return Distance(pointA, pointC);
    }
    return Math.Abs(dist);
}
```

I'm @SO not to answer but ask questions so I hope I don't get million down votes for some reasons but constructing critic. I just wanted (and was encouraged) to share somebody else's ideas since the solutions in this thread are either with some exotic language (Fortran, Mathematica) or tagged as faulty by somebody. The only useful one (by Grumdrig) for me is written with C++ and nobody tagged it faulty. But it's missing the methods (dot etc.) that are called.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. But it looks like there's an obvious optimization possible in the last method: Don't compute dist until after it's determined that it's needed.

Comment: The comment on DotProduct says it's computing AB.AC, but it's computing AB.BC.

Comment: The cross product by definition returns a vector but returns a scalar here.

Answer (score 21):

### In Mathematica

It uses a parametric description of the segment, and projects the point into the line defined by the segment. As the parameter goes from 0 to 1 in the segment, if the projection is outside this bounds, we compute the distance to the corresponding enpoint, instead of the straight line normal to the segment.

```js
Clear["Global`*"];
 distance[{start_, end_}, pt_] := 
   Module[{param},
   param = ((pt - start).(end - start))/Norm[end - start]^2; (*parameter. the "."
                                                       here means vector product*)

   Which[
    param < 0, EuclideanDistance[start, pt],                 (*If outside bounds*)
    param > 1, EuclideanDistance[end, pt],
    True, EuclideanDistance[pt, start + param (end - start)] (*Normal distance*)
    ]
   ];
```

Plotting result:

```
Plot3D[distance[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {xp, yp}], {xp, -1, 2}, {yp, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

Plot those points nearer than a **cutoff distance**:

[image]

Contour Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

For anyone interested, here's a trivial conversion of Joshua's Javascript code to Objective-C:

```c
- (double)distanceToPoint:(CGPoint)p fromLineSegmentBetween:(CGPoint)l1 and:(CGPoint)l2
{
    double A = p.x - l1.x;
    double B = p.y - l1.y;
    double C = l2.x - l1.x;
    double D = l2.y - l1.y;

    double dot = A * C + B * D;
    double len_sq = C * C + D * D;
    double param = dot / len_sq;

    double xx, yy;

    if (param < 0 || (l1.x == l2.x && l1.y == l2.y)) {
        xx = l1.x;
        yy = l1.y;
    }
    else if (param > 1) {
        xx = l2.x;
        yy = l2.y;
    }
    else {
        xx = l1.x + param * C;
        yy = l1.y + param * D;
    }

    double dx = p.x - xx;
    double dy = p.y - yy;

    return sqrtf(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

I needed this solution to work with `MKMapPoint` so I will share it in case someone else needs it. Just some minor change and this will return the distance in meters :

```c
- (double)distanceToPoint:(MKMapPoint)p fromLineSegmentBetween:(MKMapPoint)l1 and:(MKMapPoint)l2
{
    double A = p.x - l1.x;
    double B = p.y - l1.y;
    double C = l2.x - l1.x;
    double D = l2.y - l1.y;

    double dot = A * C + B * D;
    double len_sq = C * C + D * D;
    double param = dot / len_sq;

    double xx, yy;

    if (param < 0 || (l1.x == l2.x && l1.y == l2.y)) {
        xx = l1.x;
        yy = l1.y;
    }
    else if (param > 1) {
        xx = l2.x;
        yy = l2.y;
    }
    else {
        xx = l1.x + param * C;
        yy = l1.y + param * D;
    }

    return MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(p, MKMapPointMake(xx, yy));
}
```

Comment: This appears to work well for me. Thanks for converting.

Comment: It's worth noticing, that (xx, yy) is location of closest point. I've edited a bit your code, so it return both the point and distance, refactored names so they describe what is what and provided example at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28028023/849616.

Answer (score 21):

In F#, the distance from the point `c` to the line segment between `a` and `b` is given by:

```ml
let pointToLineSegmentDistance (a: Vector, b: Vector) (c: Vector) =
  let d = b - a
  let s = d.Length
  let lambda = (c - a) * d / s
  let p = (lambda |> max 0.0 |> min s) * d / s
  (a + p - c).Length
```

The vector `d` points from `a` to `b` along the line segment. The dot product of `d/s` with `c-a` gives the parameter of the point of closest approach between the infinite line and the point `c`. The `min` and `max` function are used to clamp this parameter to the range `0..s` so that the point lies between `a` and `b`. Finally, the length of `a+p-c` is the distance from `c` to the closest point on the line segment.

Example use:

```
pointToLineSegmentDistance (Vector(0.0, 0.0), Vector(1.0, 0.0)) (Vector(-1.0, 1.0))
```

Comment: I think the last line is incorrect, and should read: `(a + p - c).Length`

Comment: That still does not fully fix the issue. One way to correct the function would be to redefine `lambda` and `p` as
`let lambda = (c - a) * d / (s * s)` and
`let p = a + (lambda |> max 0.0 |> min 1.0) * d`, respectively. After that the function returns correct distance e.g. for the case where `a = (0,1)`, `b = (1,0)` and `c = (1,1)`.

Comment: Replying with code blocks sucks :/

Answer (score 11):

Hey, I just wrote this yesterday. It's in Actionscript 3.0, which is basically Javascript, though you might not have the same Point class.

```
//st = start of line segment
//b = the line segment (as in: st + b = end of line segment)
//pt = point to test
//Returns distance from point to line segment.  
//Note: nearest point on the segment to the test point is right there if we ever need it
public static function linePointDist( st:Point, b:Point, pt:Point ):Number
{
    var nearestPt:Point; //closest point on seqment to pt

    var keyDot:Number = dot( b, pt.subtract( st ) ); //key dot product
    var bLenSq:Number = dot( b, b ); //Segment length squared

    if( keyDot <= 0 )  //pt is "behind" st, use st
    {
        nearestPt = st  
    }
    else if( keyDot >= bLenSq ) //pt is "past" end of segment, use end (notice we are saving twin sqrts here cuz)
    {
        nearestPt = st.add(b);
    }
    else //pt is inside segment, reuse keyDot and bLenSq to get percent of seqment to move in to find closest point
    {
        var keyDotToPctOfB:Number = keyDot/bLenSq; //REM dot product comes squared
        var partOfB:Point = new Point( b.x * keyDotToPctOfB, b.y * keyDotToPctOfB );
        nearestPt = st.add(partOfB);
    }

    var dist:Number = (pt.subtract(nearestPt)).length;

    return dist;
}
```

Also, there's a pretty complete and readable discussion of the problem here: [notejot.com](http://notejot.com/2008/09/distance-from-point-to-line-segment-in-2d/)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly the kind of code I was looking for.  I've posted my own answer below, since I managed to put something together that works in current-era-browser-Javascript, but I've marked your answer as accepted because it's simple, well-written, easy-to-understand, and much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this missing the dot-method? In any case, it is easy to calculate: vec1.x * vec2.x + vec1.y * vec2.y

Answer (score 11):

For the lazy, here's my Objective-C port of @Grumdrig's solution above:

```
CGFloat sqr(CGFloat x) { return x*x; }
CGFloat dist2(CGPoint v, CGPoint w) { return sqr(v.x - w.x) + sqr(v.y - w.y); }
CGFloat distanceToSegmentSquared(CGPoint p, CGPoint v, CGPoint w)
{
    CGFloat l2 = dist2(v, w);
    if (l2 == 0.0f) return dist2(p, v);

    CGFloat t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
    if (t < 0.0f) return dist2(p, v);
    if (t > 1.0f) return dist2(p, w);
    return dist2(p, CGPointMake(v.x + t * (w.x - v.x), v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)));
}
CGFloat distanceToSegment(CGPoint point, CGPoint segmentPointV, CGPoint segmentPointW)
{
    return sqrtf(distanceToSegmentSquared(point, segmentPointV, segmentPointW));
}
```

Comment: I get 'nan' returned from this line. Any idea why? (Thanks for typing this up in Obj-C, by the way!)  `return dist2(p, CGPointMake(v.x + t * (w.x - v.x), v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)))`

Comment: sqrtf() is squaring x, not getting its square root

Comment: @Senseful Not sure what you mean. sqrtf is square root. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/sqrtf.3.html

Comment: @awolf: Take a look at the first line of code above. It defines the method `sqrtf(x) = x*x`.

Comment: @Senseful thanks, it was misnamed rather than performing the wrong operation.

Answer (score 11):

One line solution using arctangents:

The idea is to move **A** to (0, 0) and rotate triangle clockwise to make **C** lay on X axis,
when this happen, **By** will be the distance.

[image]

1. a angle = Atan(Cy - Ay, Cx - Ax);
2. b angle = Atan(By - Ay, Bx - Ax);
3. AB length = Sqrt( (Bx - Ax)^2 +  (By - Ay)^2 )
4. By = Sin ( bAngle - aAngle) * ABLength

C#

```
public double Distance(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
    // normalize points
    Point cn = new Point(c.X - a.X, c.Y - a.Y);
    Point bn = new Point(b.X - a.X, b.Y - a.Y);

    double angle = Math.Atan2(bn.Y, bn.X) - Math.Atan2(cn.Y, cn.X);
    double abLength = Math.Sqrt(bn.X*bn.X + bn.Y*bn.Y);

    return Math.Sin(angle)*abLength;
}
```

One line C# (to be converted to SQL)

```
double distance = Math.Sin(Math.Atan2(b.Y - a.Y, b.X - a.X) - Math.Atan2(c.Y - a.Y, c.X - a.X)) * Math.Sqrt((b.X - a.X) * (b.X - a.X) + (b.Y - a.Y) * (b.Y - a.Y))
```

Comment: This only works if b is above the line segment (b.y is not negative and b.x is between between a.x and c.x) after the rotation. It will return negative values if b is below the line after the rotation and if for example the line goes from 0,0 to 10,0 and the point b is at x,y,the distance will be y no matter what y or x are, which is the distance to a (infinitely long) line going through those two points, not the distance to a line segment.

Answer (score 10):

Couldn't resist coding it in python :)

```python
from math import sqrt, fabs
def pdis(a, b, c):
    t = b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1]           # Vector ab
    dd = sqrt(t[0]**2+t[1]**2)         # Length of ab
    t = t[0]/dd, t[1]/dd               # unit vector of ab
    n = -t[1], t[0]                    # normal unit vector to ab
    ac = c[0]-a[0], c[1]-a[1]          # vector ac
    return fabs(ac[0]*n[0]+ac[1]*n[1]) # Projection of ac to n (the minimum distance)

print pdis((1,1), (2,2), (2,0))        # Example (answer is 1.414)
```

Ditto for fortran :)

```fortran
real function pdis(a, b, c)
    real, dimension(0:1), intent(in) :: a, b, c
    real, dimension(0:1) :: t, n, ac
    real :: dd
    t = b - a                          ! Vector ab
    dd = sqrt(t(0)**2+t(1)**2)         ! Length of ab
    t = t/dd                           ! unit vector of ab
    n = (/-t(1), t(0)/)                ! normal unit vector to ab
    ac = c - a                         ! vector ac
    pdis = abs(ac(0)*n(0)+ac(1)*n(1))  ! Projection of ac to n (the minimum distance)
end function pdis


program test
    print *, pdis((/1.0,1.0/), (/2.0,2.0/), (/2.0,0.0/))   ! Example (answer is 1.414)
end program test
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This would have been really helpful when I was coding my solution, and it'll be a nice reference for the next time I need to do something like this.  I'm marking this accepted because your Python solution is short, explains its steps, and is a complete working example that I can copy/paste for testing.

Comment: isn't this computing the distance of a point to a *line* instead of the segment?

Comment: How about the projection length? What would its algorithm be?

Comment: I think I found my own answer: return fabs(ac[0]*t[0]+ac[1]*t[1])

Comment: This is indeed the distance to the line the segment is on, not to the segment.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If you've got a segment of (0,0) and (5,0), and try against point (7,0), it will return 0, which isn't true. The distance should be 2.

Comment: He's failed to consider the case where the projection of the point onto the segment is outside the interval from A to B. That might be what the questioner wanted, but not what he asked.

Comment: This is not what was originally asked.

Comment: As others have said, this algorithm is for a line, not a line segment. The quano comment explains the difference.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more complete spelling out of Grumdrig's solution. This version also returns the closest point itself.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

class Vec2
{
public:
    float _x;
    float _y;

    Vec2()
    {
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
    }

    Vec2( const float x, const float y )
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    Vec2 operator+( const Vec2 &v ) const
    {
        return Vec2( this->_x + v._x, this->_y + v._y );
    }

    Vec2 operator-( const Vec2 &v ) const
    {
        return Vec2( this->_x - v._x, this->_y - v._y );
    }

    Vec2 operator*( const float f ) const
    {
        return Vec2( this->_x * f, this->_y * f );
    }

    float DistanceToSquared( const Vec2 p ) const
    {
        const float dX = p._x - this->_x;
        const float dY = p._y - this->_y;

        return dX * dX + dY * dY;
    }

    float DistanceTo( const Vec2 p ) const
    {
        return sqrt( this->DistanceToSquared( p ) );
    }

    float DotProduct( const Vec2 p ) const
    {
        return this->_x * p._x + this->_y * p._y;
    }
};

// return minimum distance between line segment vw and point p, and the closest point on the line segment, q
float DistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( const Vec2 v, const Vec2 w, const Vec2 p, Vec2 * const q )
{
    const float distSq = v.DistanceToSquared( w ); // i.e. |w-v|^2 ... avoid a sqrt
    if ( distSq == 0.0 )
    {
        // v == w case
        (*q) = v;

        return v.DistanceTo( p );
    }

    // consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as v + t (w - v)
    // we find projection of point p onto the line
    // it falls where t = [(p-v) . (w-v)] / |w-v|^2

    const float t = ( p - v ).DotProduct( w - v ) / distSq;
    if ( t < 0.0 )
    {
        // beyond the v end of the segment
        (*q) = v;

        return v.DistanceTo( p );
    }
    else if ( t > 1.0 )
    {
        // beyond the w end of the segment
        (*q) = w;

        return w.DistanceTo( p );
    }

    // projection falls on the segment
    const Vec2 projection = v + ( ( w - v ) * t );

    (*q) = projection;

    return p.DistanceTo( projection );
}

float DistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( float segmentX1, float segmentY1, float segmentX2, float segmentY2, float pX, float pY, float *qX, float *qY )
{
    Vec2 q;

    float distance = DistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( Vec2( segmentX1, segmentY1 ), Vec2( segmentX2, segmentY2 ), Vec2( pX, pY ), &q );

    (*qX) = q._x;
    (*qY) = q._y;

    return distance;
}

void TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( float segmentX1, float segmentY1, float segmentX2, float segmentY2, float pX, float pY )
{
    float qX;
    float qY;
    float d = DistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( segmentX1, segmentY1, segmentX2, segmentY2, pX, pY, &qX, &qY );
    printf( "line segment = ( ( %f, %f ), ( %f, %f ) ), p = ( %f, %f ), distance = %f, q = ( %f, %f )\n",
            segmentX1, segmentY1, segmentX2, segmentY2, pX, pY, d, qX, qY );
}

void TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint()
{
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 );
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 20, 10, 5, 4 );
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 20, 10, 30, 15 );
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 20, 10, -30, 15 );
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 1 );
    TestDistanceFromLineSegmentToPoint( 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 5 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Very well structured and commented and formatted - almost made me forget how much I dislike C++. I've used this to make a corresponding C# version, which I've now posted here.

Answer (score 7):

Consider this modification to Grumdrig's answer above.  Many times you'll find that floating point imprecision can cause problems.   I'm using doubles in the version below, but you can easily change to floats.  The important part is that it uses an epsilon to handle the "slop".  In addition, you'll many times want to know WHERE the intersection happened, or if it happened at all.  If the returned t is < 0.0 or > 1.0, no collision occurred.  However, even if no collision occurred, many times you'll want to know where the closest point on the segment to P is, and thus I use qx and qy to return this location.

```
double PointSegmentDistanceSquared( double px, double py,
                                    double p1x, double p1y,
                                    double p2x, double p2y,
                                    double& t,
                                    double& qx, double& qy)
{
    static const double kMinSegmentLenSquared = 0.00000001;  // adjust to suit.  If you use float, you'll probably want something like 0.000001f
    static const double kEpsilon = 1.0E-14;  // adjust to suit.  If you use floats, you'll probably want something like 1E-7f
    double dx = p2x - p1x;
    double dy = p2y - p1y;
    double dp1x = px - p1x;
    double dp1y = py - p1y;
    const double segLenSquared = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
    if (segLenSquared >= -kMinSegmentLenSquared && segLenSquared <= kMinSegmentLenSquared)
    {
        // segment is a point.
        qx = p1x;
        qy = p1y;
        t = 0.0;
        return ((dp1x * dp1x) + (dp1y * dp1y));
    }
    else
    {
        // Project a line from p to the segment [p1,p2].  By considering the line
        // extending the segment, parameterized as p1 + (t * (p2 - p1)),
        // we find projection of point p onto the line. 
        // It falls where t = [(p - p1) . (p2 - p1)] / |p2 - p1|^2
        t = ((dp1x * dx) + (dp1y * dy)) / segLenSquared;
        if (t < kEpsilon)
        {
            // intersects at or to the "left" of first segment vertex (p1x, p1y).  If t is approximately 0.0, then
            // intersection is at p1.  If t is less than that, then there is no intersection (i.e. p is not within
            // the 'bounds' of the segment)
            if (t > -kEpsilon)
            {
                // intersects at 1st segment vertex
                t = 0.0;
            }
            // set our 'intersection' point to p1.
            qx = p1x;
            qy = p1y;
            // Note: If you wanted the ACTUAL intersection point of where the projected lines would intersect if
            // we were doing PointLineDistanceSquared, then qx would be (p1x + (t * dx)) and qy would be (p1y + (t * dy)).
        }
        else if (t > (1.0 - kEpsilon))
        {
            // intersects at or to the "right" of second segment vertex (p2x, p2y).  If t is approximately 1.0, then
            // intersection is at p2.  If t is greater than that, then there is no intersection (i.e. p is not within
            // the 'bounds' of the segment)
            if (t < (1.0 + kEpsilon))
            {
                // intersects at 2nd segment vertex
                t = 1.0;
            }
            // set our 'intersection' point to p2.
            qx = p2x;
            qy = p2y;
            // Note: If you wanted the ACTUAL intersection point of where the projected lines would intersect if
            // we were doing PointLineDistanceSquared, then qx would be (p1x + (t * dx)) and qy would be (p1y + (t * dy)).
        }
        else
        {
            // The projection of the point to the point on the segment that is perpendicular succeeded and the point
            // is 'within' the bounds of the segment.  Set the intersection point as that projected point.
            qx = p1x + (t * dx);
            qy = p1y + (t * dy);
        }
        // return the squared distance from p to the intersection point.  Note that we return the squared distance
        // as an optimization because many times you just need to compare relative distances and the squared values
        // works fine for that.  If you want the ACTUAL distance, just take the square root of this value.
        double dpqx = px - qx;
        double dpqy = py - qy;
        return ((dpqx * dpqx) + (dpqy * dpqy));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to find the **shortest** distance between the point and a line segment; to do this, you need to find the line (lineA) which is perpendicular to your line segment (lineB) which goes through your point, determine the intersection between that line (lineA) and your line which goes through your line segment (lineB); if that point is between the two points of your line segment, then the distance is the distance between your point and the point you just found  which is the intersection of lineA and lineB; if the point is not between the two points of your line segment, you need to get the distance between your point and the closer of two ends of the line segment; this can be done easily by taking the square distance (to avoid a square root) between the point and the two points of the line segment; whichever is closer, take the square root of that one.

Answer (score 6):

Grumdrig's C++/JavaScript implementation was very useful to me, so I have provided a Python direct port that I am using. The complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/irees/be5e56e7c9b16d78a351).

```
class Point(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = float(x)
    self.y = float(y)

def square(x):
  return x * x

def distance_squared(v, w):
  return square(v.x - w.x) + square(v.y - w.y)

def distance_point_segment_squared(p, v, w):
  # Segment length squared, |w-v|^2
  d2 = distance_squared(v, w) 
  if d2 == 0: 
    # v == w, return distance to v
    return distance_squared(p, v)
  # Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as v + t (w - v).
  # We find projection of point p onto the line.
  # It falls where t = [(p-v) . (w-v)] / |w-v|^2
  t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / d2;
  if t < 0:
    # Beyond v end of the segment
    return distance_squared(p, v)
  elif t > 1.0:
    # Beyond w end of the segment
    return distance_squared(p, w)
  else:
    # Projection falls on the segment.
    proj = Point(v.x + t * (w.x - v.x), v.y + t * (w.y - v.y))
    # print proj.x, proj.y
    return distance_squared(p, proj)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here it is using Swift

```
    /* Distance from a point (p1) to line l1 l2 */
func distanceFromPoint(p: CGPoint, toLineSegment l1: CGPoint, and l2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let A = p.x - l1.x
    let B = p.y - l1.y
    let C = l2.x - l1.x
    let D = l2.y - l1.y
    
    let dot = A * C + B * D
    let len_sq = C * C + D * D
    var param : CGFloat = -1
    if len_sq != 0 {
        param = dot / len_sq
    }
    
    var xx, yy: CGFloat
    
    if param < 0 || (l1.x == l2.x && l1.y == l2.y) {
        xx = l1.x
        yy = l1.y
    } else if param > 1 {
        xx = l2.x
        yy = l2.y
    } else {
        xx = l1.x + param * C
        yy = l1.y + param * D
    }
    
    let dx = p.x - xx
    let dy = p.y - yy
    
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Matlab code, with built-in "self test" if they call the function with no arguments:

```
function r = distPointToLineSegment( xy0, xy1, xyP )
% r = distPointToLineSegment( xy0, xy1, xyP )

if( nargin < 3 )
    selfTest();
    r=0;
else
    vx = xy0(1)-xyP(1);
    vy = xy0(2)-xyP(2);
    ux = xy1(1)-xy0(1);
    uy = xy1(2)-xy0(2);
    lenSqr= (ux*ux+uy*uy);
    detP= -vx*ux + -vy*uy;

    if( detP < 0 )
        r = norm(xy0-xyP,2);
    elseif( detP > lenSqr )
        r = norm(xy1-xyP,2);
    else
        r = abs(ux*vy-uy*vx)/sqrt(lenSqr);
    end
end


    function selfTest()
        %#ok<*NASGU>
        disp(['invalid args, distPointToLineSegment running (recursive)  self-test...']);

        ptA = [1;1]; ptB = [-1;-1];
        ptC = [1/2;1/2];  % on the line
        ptD = [-2;-1.5];  % too far from line segment
        ptE = [1/2;0];    % should be same as perpendicular distance to line
        ptF = [1.5;1.5];      % along the A-B but outside of the segment

        distCtoAB = distPointToLineSegment(ptA,ptB,ptC)
        distDtoAB = distPointToLineSegment(ptA,ptB,ptD)
        distEtoAB = distPointToLineSegment(ptA,ptB,ptE)
        distFtoAB = distPointToLineSegment(ptA,ptB,ptF)
        figure(1); clf;
        circle = @(x, y, r, c) rectangle('Position', [x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r], ...
            'Curvature', [1 1], 'EdgeColor', c);
        plot([ptA(1) ptB(1)],[ptA(2) ptB(2)],'r-x'); hold on;
        plot(ptC(1),ptC(2),'b+'); circle(ptC(1),ptC(2), 0.5e-1, 'b');
        plot(ptD(1),ptD(2),'g+'); circle(ptD(1),ptD(2), distDtoAB, 'g');
        plot(ptE(1),ptE(2),'k+'); circle(ptE(1),ptE(2), distEtoAB, 'k');
        plot(ptF(1),ptF(2),'m+'); circle(ptF(1),ptF(2), distFtoAB, 'm');
        hold off;
        axis([-3 3 -3 3]); axis equal;
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, this Matlab code indeed calculates the shortest distance to the line **SEGMENT** and not the distance to the infinite line on which the segment lies.

Answer (score 5):

And now my solution as well......
(Javascript)

It is very fast because I try to avoid any Math.pow functions.

As you can see, at the end of the function I have the distance of the line.

*code is from the lib http://www.draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example*

```
/**
 * Static util function to determine is a point(px,py) on the line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
 * A simple hit test.
 * 
 * @return {boolean}
 * @static
 * @private
 * @param {Number} coronaWidth the accepted corona for the hit test
 * @param {Number} X1 x coordinate of the start point of the line
 * @param {Number} Y1 y coordinate of the start point of the line
 * @param {Number} X2 x coordinate of the end point of the line
 * @param {Number} Y2 y coordinate of the end point of the line
 * @param {Number} px x coordinate of the point to test
 * @param {Number} py y coordinate of the point to test
 **/
graphiti.shape.basic.Line.hit= function( coronaWidth, X1, Y1,  X2,  Y2, px, py)
{
  // Adjust vectors relative to X1,Y1
  // X2,Y2 becomes relative vector from X1,Y1 to end of segment
  X2 -= X1;
  Y2 -= Y1;
  // px,py becomes relative vector from X1,Y1 to test point
  px -= X1;
  py -= Y1;
  var dotprod = px * X2 + py * Y2;
  var projlenSq;
  if (dotprod <= 0.0) {
      // px,py is on the side of X1,Y1 away from X2,Y2
      // distance to segment is length of px,py vector
      // "length of its (clipped) projection" is now 0.0
      projlenSq = 0.0;
  } else {
      // switch to backwards vectors relative to X2,Y2
      // X2,Y2 are already the negative of X1,Y1=>X2,Y2
      // to get px,py to be the negative of px,py=>X2,Y2
      // the dot product of two negated vectors is the same
      // as the dot product of the two normal vectors
      px = X2 - px;
      py = Y2 - py;
      dotprod = px * X2 + py * Y2;
      if (dotprod <= 0.0) {
          // px,py is on the side of X2,Y2 away from X1,Y1
          // distance to segment is length of (backwards) px,py vector
          // "length of its (clipped) projection" is now 0.0
          projlenSq = 0.0;
      } else {
          // px,py is between X1,Y1 and X2,Y2
          // dotprod is the length of the px,py vector
          // projected on the X2,Y2=>X1,Y1 vector times the
          // length of the X2,Y2=>X1,Y1 vector
          projlenSq = dotprod * dotprod / (X2 * X2 + Y2 * Y2);
      }
  }
    // Distance to line is now the length of the relative point
    // vector minus the length of its projection onto the line
    // (which is zero if the projection falls outside the range
    //  of the line segment).
    var lenSq = px * px + py * py - projlenSq;
    if (lenSq < 0) {
        lenSq = 0;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(lenSq)<coronaWidth;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

**C#**

Adapted from [@Grumdrig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501725/365102)

```cs
public static double MinimumDistanceToLineSegment(this Point p,
    Line line)
{
    var v = line.StartPoint;
    var w = line.EndPoint;

    double lengthSquared = DistanceSquared(v, w);

    if (lengthSquared == 0.0)
        return Distance(p, v);

    double t = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(1, DotProduct(p - v, w - v) / lengthSquared));
    var projection = v + t * (w - v);

    return Distance(p, projection);
}

public static double Distance(Point a, Point b)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(DistanceSquared(a, b));
}

public static double DistanceSquared(Point a, Point b)
{
    var d = a - b;
    return DotProduct(d, d);
}

public static double DotProduct(Point a, Point b)
{
    return (a.X * b.X) + (a.Y * b.Y);
}
```

Comment: Tried this code, doesn't seem to work quite correctly. Seems to get the wrong distance some times.

Answer (score 4):

coded in t-sql

the point is (@px, @py) and the line segment runs from (@ax, @ay) to (@bx, @by)

```
create function fn_sqr (@NumberToSquare decimal(18,10)) 
returns decimal(18,10)
as 
begin
    declare @Result decimal(18,10)
    set @Result = @NumberToSquare * @NumberToSquare
    return @Result
end
go

create function fn_Distance(@ax decimal (18,10) , @ay decimal (18,10), @bx decimal(18,10),  @by decimal(18,10)) 
returns decimal(18,10)
as
begin
    declare @Result decimal(18,10)
    set @Result = (select dbo.fn_sqr(@ax - @bx) + dbo.fn_sqr(@ay - @by) )
    return @Result
end
go

create function fn_DistanceToSegmentSquared(@px decimal(18,10), @py decimal(18,10), @ax decimal(18,10), @ay decimal(18,10), @bx decimal(18,10), @by decimal(18,10)) 
returns decimal(18,10)
as 
begin
    declare @l2 decimal(18,10)
    set @l2 = (select dbo.fn_Distance(@ax, @ay, @bx, @by))
    if @l2 = 0
        return dbo.fn_Distance(@px, @py, @ax, @ay)
    declare @t decimal(18,10)
    set @t = ((@px - @ax) * (@bx - @ax) + (@py - @ay) * (@by - @ay)) / @l2
    if (@t < 0) 
        return dbo.fn_Distance(@px, @py, @ax, @ay);
    if (@t > 1) 
        return dbo.fn_Distance(@px, @py, @bx, @by);
    return dbo.fn_Distance(@px, @py,  @ax + @t * (@bx - @ax),  @ay + @t * (@by - @ay))
end
go

create function fn_DistanceToSegment(@px decimal(18,10), @py decimal(18,10), @ax decimal(18,10), @ay decimal(18,10), @bx decimal(18,10), @by decimal(18,10)) 
returns decimal(18,10)
as 
begin
    return sqrt(dbo.fn_DistanceToSegmentSquared(@px, @py , @ax , @ay , @bx , @by ))
end
go

--example execution for distance from a point at (6,1) to line segment that runs from (4,2) to (2,1)
select dbo.fn_DistanceToSegment(6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1) 
--result = 2.2360679775

--example execution for distance from a point at (-3,-2) to line segment that runs from (0,-2) to (-2,1)
select dbo.fn_DistanceToSegment(-3, -2, 0, -2, -2, 1) 
--result = 2.4961508830

--example execution for distance from a point at (0,-2) to line segment that runs from (0,-2) to (-2,1)
select dbo.fn_DistanceToSegment(0,-2, 0, -2, -2, 1) 
--result = 0.0000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like just about everyone else on StackOverflow has contributed an answer (23 answers so far), so here's my contribution for C#. This is mostly based on the answer by M. Katz, which in turn is based on the answer by Grumdrig.

```
   public struct MyVector
   {
      private readonly double _x, _y;


      // Constructor
      public MyVector(double x, double y)
      {
         _x = x;
         _y = y;
      }


      // Distance from this point to another point, squared
      private double DistanceSquared(MyVector otherPoint)
      {
         double dx = otherPoint._x - this._x;
         double dy = otherPoint._y - this._y;
         return dx * dx + dy * dy;
      }


      // Find the distance from this point to a line segment (which is not the same as from this 
      //  point to anywhere on an infinite line). Also returns the closest point.
      public double DistanceToLineSegment(MyVector lineSegmentPoint1, MyVector lineSegmentPoint2,
                                          out MyVector closestPoint)
      {
         return Math.Sqrt(DistanceToLineSegmentSquared(lineSegmentPoint1, lineSegmentPoint2, 
                          out closestPoint));
      }


      // Same as above, but avoid using Sqrt(), saves a new nanoseconds in cases where you only want 
      //  to compare several distances to find the smallest or largest, but don't need the distance
      public double DistanceToLineSegmentSquared(MyVector lineSegmentPoint1, 
                                              MyVector lineSegmentPoint2, out MyVector closestPoint)
      {
         // Compute length of line segment (squared) and handle special case of coincident points
         double segmentLengthSquared = lineSegmentPoint1.DistanceSquared(lineSegmentPoint2);
         if (segmentLengthSquared < 1E-7f)  // Arbitrary "close enough for government work" value
         {
            closestPoint = lineSegmentPoint1;
            return this.DistanceSquared(closestPoint);
         }

         // Use the magic formula to compute the "projection" of this point on the infinite line
         MyVector lineSegment = lineSegmentPoint2 - lineSegmentPoint1;
         double t = (this - lineSegmentPoint1).DotProduct(lineSegment) / segmentLengthSquared;

         // Handle the two cases where the projection is not on the line segment, and the case where 
         //  the projection is on the segment
         if (t <= 0)
            closestPoint = lineSegmentPoint1;
         else if (t >= 1)
            closestPoint = lineSegmentPoint2;
         else 
            closestPoint = lineSegmentPoint1 + (lineSegment * t);
         return this.DistanceSquared(closestPoint);
      }


      public double DotProduct(MyVector otherVector)
      {
         return this._x * otherVector._x + this._y * otherVector._y;
      }

      public static MyVector operator +(MyVector leftVector, MyVector rightVector)
      {
         return new MyVector(leftVector._x + rightVector._x, leftVector._y + rightVector._y);
      }

      public static MyVector operator -(MyVector leftVector, MyVector rightVector)
      {
         return new MyVector(leftVector._x - rightVector._x, leftVector._y - rightVector._y);
      }

      public static MyVector operator *(MyVector aVector, double aScalar)
      {
         return new MyVector(aVector._x * aScalar, aVector._y * aScalar);
      }

      // Added using ReSharper due to CodeAnalysis nagging

      public bool Equals(MyVector other)
      {
         return _x.Equals(other._x) && _y.Equals(other._y);
      }

      public override bool Equals(object obj)
      {
         if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
         return obj is MyVector && Equals((MyVector) obj);
      }

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
         unchecked
         {
            return (_x.GetHashCode()*397) ^ _y.GetHashCode();
         }
      }

      public static bool operator ==(MyVector left, MyVector right)
      {
         return left.Equals(right);
      }

      public static bool operator !=(MyVector left, MyVector right)
      {
         return !left.Equals(right);
      }
   }
```

And here's a little test program.

```
   public static class JustTesting
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
         stopwatch.Start();

         for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
         {
            TestIt(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.70710678118654757);
            TestIt(5, 4, 0, 0, 20, 10, 1.3416407864998738);
            TestIt(30, 15, 0, 0, 20, 10, 11.180339887498949);
            TestIt(-30, 15, 0, 0, 20, 10, 33.541019662496844);
            TestIt(5, 1, 0, 0, 10, 0, 1.0);
            TestIt(1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1.0);
         }

         stopwatch.Stop();
         TimeSpan timeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed;
      }


      private static void TestIt(float aPointX, float aPointY, 
                                 float lineSegmentPoint1X, float lineSegmentPoint1Y, 
                                 float lineSegmentPoint2X, float lineSegmentPoint2Y, 
                                 double expectedAnswer)
      {
         // Katz
         double d1 = DistanceFromPointToLineSegment(new MyVector(aPointX, aPointY), 
                                              new MyVector(lineSegmentPoint1X, lineSegmentPoint1Y), 
                                              new MyVector(lineSegmentPoint2X, lineSegmentPoint2Y));
         Debug.Assert(d1 == expectedAnswer);

         /*
         // Katz using squared distance
         double d2 = DistanceFromPointToLineSegmentSquared(new MyVector(aPointX, aPointY), 
                                              new MyVector(lineSegmentPoint1X, lineSegmentPoint1Y), 
                                              new MyVector(lineSegmentPoint2X, lineSegmentPoint2Y));
         Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(d2 - expectedAnswer * expectedAnswer) < 1E-7f);
          */

         /*
         // Matti (optimized)
         double d3 = FloatVector.DistanceToLineSegment(new PointF(aPointX, aPointY), 
                                                new PointF(lineSegmentPoint1X, lineSegmentPoint1Y), 
                                                new PointF(lineSegmentPoint2X, lineSegmentPoint2Y));
         Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(d3 - expectedAnswer) < 1E-7f);
          */
      }

      private static double DistanceFromPointToLineSegment(MyVector aPoint, 
                                             MyVector lineSegmentPoint1, MyVector lineSegmentPoint2)
      {
         MyVector closestPoint;  // Not used
         return aPoint.DistanceToLineSegment(lineSegmentPoint1, lineSegmentPoint2, 
                                             out closestPoint);
      }

      private static double DistanceFromPointToLineSegmentSquared(MyVector aPoint, 
                                             MyVector lineSegmentPoint1, MyVector lineSegmentPoint2)
      {
         MyVector closestPoint;  // Not used
         return aPoint.DistanceToLineSegmentSquared(lineSegmentPoint1, lineSegmentPoint2, 
                                                    out closestPoint);
      }
   }
```

As you can see, I tried to measure the difference between using the version that avoids the Sqrt() method and the normal version. My tests indicate you can maybe save about 2.5%, but I'm not even sure of that - the variations within the various test runs were of the same order of magnitude. I also tried measuring the version posted by Matti (plus an obvious optimization), and that version seems to be about 4% slower than the version based on Katz/Grumdrig code.

Edit: Incidentally, I've also tried measuring a method that finds the distance to an infinite line (not a line segment) using a cross product (and a Sqrt()), and it's about 32% faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here is devnullicus's C++ version converted to C#. For my implementation I needed to know the point of intersection and found his solution to work well.

```
public static bool PointSegmentDistanceSquared(PointF point, PointF lineStart, PointF lineEnd, out double distance, out PointF intersectPoint)
{
    const double kMinSegmentLenSquared = 0.00000001; // adjust to suit.  If you use float, you'll probably want something like 0.000001f
    const double kEpsilon = 1.0E-14; // adjust to suit.  If you use floats, you'll probably want something like 1E-7f
    double dX = lineEnd.X - lineStart.X;
    double dY = lineEnd.Y - lineStart.Y;
    double dp1X = point.X - lineStart.X;
    double dp1Y = point.Y - lineStart.Y;
    double segLenSquared = (dX * dX) + (dY * dY);
    double t = 0.0;

    if (segLenSquared >= -kMinSegmentLenSquared && segLenSquared <= kMinSegmentLenSquared)
    {
        // segment is a point.
        intersectPoint = lineStart;
        t = 0.0;
        distance = ((dp1X * dp1X) + (dp1Y * dp1Y));
    }
    else
    {
        // Project a line from p to the segment [p1,p2].  By considering the line
        // extending the segment, parameterized as p1 + (t * (p2 - p1)),
        // we find projection of point p onto the line. 
        // It falls where t = [(p - p1) . (p2 - p1)] / |p2 - p1|^2
        t = ((dp1X * dX) + (dp1Y * dY)) / segLenSquared;
        if (t < kEpsilon)
        {
            // intersects at or to the "left" of first segment vertex (lineStart.X, lineStart.Y).  If t is approximately 0.0, then
            // intersection is at p1.  If t is less than that, then there is no intersection (i.e. p is not within
            // the 'bounds' of the segment)
            if (t > -kEpsilon)
            {
                // intersects at 1st segment vertex
                t = 0.0;
            }
            // set our 'intersection' point to p1.
            intersectPoint = lineStart;
            // Note: If you wanted the ACTUAL intersection point of where the projected lines would intersect if
            // we were doing PointLineDistanceSquared, then intersectPoint.X would be (lineStart.X + (t * dx)) and intersectPoint.Y would be (lineStart.Y + (t * dy)).
        }
        else if (t > (1.0 - kEpsilon))
        {
            // intersects at or to the "right" of second segment vertex (lineEnd.X, lineEnd.Y).  If t is approximately 1.0, then
            // intersection is at p2.  If t is greater than that, then there is no intersection (i.e. p is not within
            // the 'bounds' of the segment)
            if (t < (1.0 + kEpsilon))
            {
                // intersects at 2nd segment vertex
                t = 1.0;
            }
            // set our 'intersection' point to p2.
            intersectPoint = lineEnd;
            // Note: If you wanted the ACTUAL intersection point of where the projected lines would intersect if
            // we were doing PointLineDistanceSquared, then intersectPoint.X would be (lineStart.X + (t * dx)) and intersectPoint.Y would be (lineStart.Y + (t * dy)).
        }
        else
        {
            // The projection of the point to the point on the segment that is perpendicular succeeded and the point
            // is 'within' the bounds of the segment.  Set the intersection point as that projected point.
            intersectPoint = new PointF((float)(lineStart.X + (t * dX)), (float)(lineStart.Y + (t * dY)));
        }
        // return the squared distance from p to the intersection point.  Note that we return the squared distance
        // as an optimization because many times you just need to compare relative distances and the squared values
        // works fine for that.  If you want the ACTUAL distance, just take the square root of this value.
        double dpqX = point.X - intersectPoint.X;
        double dpqY = point.Y - intersectPoint.Y;

        distance = ((dpqX * dpqX) + (dpqY * dpqY));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Saved me countless hours. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

**A 2D and 3D solution**

Consider a change of basis such that the line segment becomes `(0, 0, 0)-(d, 0, 0)` and the point `(u, v, 0)`. The shortest distance occurs in that plane and is given by

```
    u ≤ 0 -> d(A, C)
0 ≤ u ≤ d -> |v|
d ≤ u     -> d(B, C)
```

(the distance to one of the endpoints or to the supporting line, depending on the projection to the line. The iso-distance locus is made of two half-circles and two line segments.)

[image]

In the above expression, d is the length of the segment AB, and u, v are respectivey the scalar product and (modulus of the) cross product of AB/d (unit vector in the direction of AB) and AC. Hence vectorially,

```
AB.AC ≤ 0             -> |AC|
    0 ≤ AB.AC ≤ AB²   -> |ABxAC|/|AB|
          AB² ≤ AB.AC -> |BC|
```

Answer (score 3):

C# Version

```
public static FP DistanceToLineSegment(FPVector3 a, FPVector3 b, FPVector3 point)
{
  var d = b - a;
  var s = d.SqrMagnitude;
  var ds = d / s;
  var lambda = FPVector3.Dot(point - a, ds);
  var p = FPMath.Clamp01(lambda) * d;
  return (a + p - point).Magnitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above function is not working on vertical lines. Here is a function that is working fine!
Line with points p1, p2. and CheckPoint is p;

```
public float DistanceOfPointToLine2(PointF p1, PointF p2, PointF p)
{
  //          (y1-y2)x + (x2-x1)y + (x1y2-x2y1)
  //d(P,L) = --------------------------------
  //         sqrt( (x2-x1)pow2 + (y2-y1)pow2 )

  double ch = (p1.Y - p2.Y) * p.X + (p2.X - p1.X) * p.Y + (p1.X * p2.Y - p2.X * p1.Y);
  double del = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2.X - p1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.Y - p1.Y, 2));
  double d = ch / del;
  return (float)d;
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. This only works for lines (the ones that extend infinitely in space) not line segments (which have a finite length).

Comment: "above function" is an ambiguous reference. (Irritates me because sometimes this answer is shown beneath my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

see the Matlab GEOMETRY toolbox in the following website:
http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/geometry/geometry.html

ctrl+f and type "segment" to find line segment related functions. the functions "segment_point_dist_2d.m" and "segment_point_dist_3d.m" are what you need.

The GEOMETRY codes are available in a C version and a C++ version and a FORTRAN77 version and a FORTRAN90 version and a MATLAB version.

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotkeys version based on Joshua's Javascript:

```
plDist(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    A:= x - x1
    B:= y - y1
    C:= x2 - x1
    D:= y2 - y1

    dot:= A*C + B*D
    sqLen:= C*C + D*D
    param:= dot / sqLen

    if (param < 0 || ((x1 = x2) && (y1 = y2))) {
        xx:= x1
        yy:= y1
    } else if (param > 1) {
        xx:= x2
        yy:= y2
    } else {
        xx:= x1 + param*C
        yy:= y1 + param*D
    }

    dx:= x - xx
    dy:= y - yy

    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the accepted answer does not work 
(e.g. distance between 0,0 and (-10,2,10,2) should be 2).

here's code that works:

```
   def dist2line2(x,y,line):
     x1,y1,x2,y2=line
     vx = x1 - x
     vy = y1 - y
     ux = x2-x1
     uy = y2-y1
     length = ux * ux + uy * uy
     det = (-vx * ux) + (-vy * uy) #//if this is < 0 or > length then its outside the line segment
     if det < 0:
       return (x1 - x)**2 + (y1 - y)**2
     if det > length:
       return (x2 - x)**2 + (y2 - y)**2
     det = ux * vy - uy * vx
     return det**2 / length
   def dist2line(x,y,line): return math.sqrt(dist2line2(x,y,line))
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't see a Java implementation here, so I translated the Javascript function from the accepted answer to Java code:

```
static double sqr(double x) {
    return x * x;
}
static double dist2(DoublePoint v, DoublePoint w) {
    return sqr(v.x - w.x) + sqr(v.y - w.y);
}
static double distToSegmentSquared(DoublePoint p, DoublePoint v, DoublePoint w) {
    double l2 = dist2(v, w);
    if (l2 == 0) return dist2(p, v);
    double t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
    if (t < 0) return dist2(p, v);
    if (t > 1) return dist2(p, w);
    return dist2(p, new DoublePoint(
            v.x + t * (w.x - v.x),
            v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)
    ));
}
static double distToSegment(DoublePoint p, DoublePoint v, DoublePoint w) {
    return Math.sqrt(distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w));
}
static class DoublePoint {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public DoublePoint(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WPF version:

```
public class LineSegment
{
    private readonly Vector _offset;
    private readonly Vector _vector;

    public LineSegment(Point start, Point end)
    {
        _offset = (Vector)start;
        _vector = (Vector)(end - _offset);
    }

    public double DistanceTo(Point pt)
    {
        var v = (Vector)pt - _offset;

        // first, find a projection point on the segment in parametric form (0..1)
        var p = (v * _vector) / _vector.LengthSquared;

        // and limit it so it lays inside the segment
        p = Math.Min(Math.Max(p, 0), 1);

        // now, find the distance from that point to our point
        return (_vector * p - v).Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made an interactive Desmos graph to demonstrate how to achieve this:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kswrm8ddum

The red point is A, the green point is B, and the point C is blue.
You can drag the points in the graph to see the values change.
On the left, the value 's' is the parameter of the line segment (i.e. s = 0 means the point A, and s = 1 means the point B).
The value 'd' is the distance from the third point to the line through A and B.

EDIT:

Fun little insight: the coordinate (s, d) is the coordinate of the third point C in the coordinate system where AB is the unit x-axis, and the unit y-axis is perpendicular to AB.

Answer (score 2):

Python Numpy implementation for 2D coordinate array:

```python
import numpy as np


def dist2d(p1, p2, coords):
    ''' Distance from points to a finite line btwn p1 -> p2 '''
    assert coords.ndim == 2 and coords.shape[1] == 2, 'coords is not 2 dim'
    dp = p2 - p1
    st = dp[0]**2 + dp[1]**2
    u = ((coords[:, 0] - p1[0]) * dp[0] + (coords[:, 1] - p1[1]) * dp[1]) / st

    u[u > 1.] = 1.
    u[u < 0.] = 0.

    dx = (p1[0] + u * dp[0]) - coords[:, 0]
    dy = (p1[1] + u * dp[1]) - coords[:, 1]

    return np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)


# Usage:
p1 = np.array([0., 0.])
p2 = np.array([0., 10.])

# List of coordinates
coords = np.array(
    [[0., 0.],
     [5., 5.],
     [10., 10.],
     [20., 20.]
     ])

d = dist2d(p1, p2, coords)

# Single coordinate
coord = np.array([25., 25.])
d = dist2d(p1, p2, coord[np.newaxis, :])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I ended up writing.  This code assumes that a point is defined in the form of `{x:5, y:7}`.  Note that this is not the absolute most efficient way, but it's the simplest and easiest-to-understand code that I could come up with.

```
// a, b, and c in the code below are all points

function distance(a, b)
{
    var dx = a.x - b.x;
    var dy = a.y - b.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

function Segment(a, b)
{
    var ab = {
        x: b.x - a.x,
        y: b.y - a.y
    };
    var length = distance(a, b);

    function cross(c) {
        return ab.x * (c.y-a.y) - ab.y * (c.x-a.x);
    };

    this.distanceFrom = function(c) {
        return Math.min(distance(a,c),
                        distance(b,c),
                        Math.abs(cross(c) / length));
    };
}
```

Comment: This code has a bug. A point near the line on which the segment lies, but far off one end of the segment, would be incorrectly judged to be near the segment.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into this the next time I'm working on this codebase to confirm your assertion.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is same thing as the C++ answer but ported to pascal. The order of the point parameter has changed to suit my code but is the same thing.

```
function Dot(const p1, p2: PointF): double;
begin
  Result := p1.x * p2.x + p1.y * p2.y;
end;
function SubPoint(const p1, p2: PointF): PointF;
begin
  result.x := p1.x - p2.x;
  result.y := p1.y - p2.y;
end;

function ShortestDistance2(const p,v,w : PointF) : double;
var
  l2,t : double;
  projection,tt: PointF;
begin
  // Return minimum distance between line segment vw and point p
  //l2 := length_squared(v, w);  // i.e. |w-v|^2 -  avoid a sqrt
  l2 := Distance(v,w);
  l2 := MPower(l2,2);
  if (l2 = 0.0) then begin
    result:= Distance(p, v);   // v == w case
    exit;
  end;
  // Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as v + t (w - v).
  // We find projection of point p onto the line.
  // It falls where t = [(p-v) . (w-v)] / |w-v|^2
  t := Dot(SubPoint(p,v),SubPoint(w,v)) / l2;
  if (t < 0.0) then begin
    result := Distance(p, v);       // Beyond the 'v' end of the segment
    exit;
  end
  else if (t > 1.0) then begin
    result := Distance(p, w);  // Beyond the 'w' end of the segment
    exit;
  end;
  //projection := v + t * (w - v);  // Projection falls on the segment
  tt.x := v.x + t * (w.x - v.x);
  tt.y := v.y + t * (w.y - v.y);
  result := Distance(p, tt);
end;
```

Comment: There are several problems with this Answer: The type PointF is not declared (maybe that's a standard type in some Pascal implementations). It's probably a record x,y: double; end; 2. the functions Distance and MPower are not declared and there is no explanation what they do (we can guess, yes). 3. The variable projection is declared but never used. Overall that makes it a rather poor answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
%Matlab solution by Tim from Cody
function ans=distP2S(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2)
% Point is x0,y0
z=complex(x0-x1,y0-y1);
complex(x2-x1,y2-y1);
abs(z-ans*min(1,max(0,real(z/ans))));
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is based on finding the intersection between the specified line and the orthogonal line, which contains the specified point, and calculating its distance. In case of a line segment, we must check if the intersection is between points of the line segment, if that's not the case then the minimum distance is between the specified point and one of the ending points of the line segment. This is a C# implementation.

```
Double Distance(Point a, Point b)
{
    double xdiff = a.X - b.X, ydiff = a.Y - b.Y;
    return Math.Sqrt((long)xdiff * xdiff + (long)ydiff * ydiff);
}

Boolean IsBetween(double x, double a, double b)
{
    return ((a <= b && x >= a && x <= b) || (a > b && x <= a && x >= b));
}

Double GetDistance(Point pt, Point pt1, Point pt2, out Point intersection)
{
    Double a, x, y, R;

    if (pt1.X != pt2.X) {
        a = (double)(pt2.Y - pt1.Y) / (pt2.X - pt1.X);
        x = (a * (pt.Y - pt1.Y) + a * a * pt1.X + pt.X) / (a * a + 1);
        y = a * x + pt1.Y - a * pt1.X; }
    else { x = pt1.X;  y = pt.Y; }

    if (IsBetween(x, pt1.X, pt2.X) && IsBetween(y, pt1.Y, pt2.Y)) {
        intersection = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
        R = Distance(intersection, pt); }
    else {
        double d1 = Distance(pt, pt1), d2 = Distance(pt, pt2);
        if (d1 < d2) { intersection = pt1; R = d1; }
        else { intersection = pt2; R = d2; }}

    return R;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Needed to find the intersection in Java, and this translated perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

GLSL version:

```
// line (a -> b ) point p[enter image description here][1]
float distanceToLine(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 p) {
    float aside = dot((p - a),(b - a));
    if(aside< 0.0) return length(p-a);
    float bside = dot((p - b),(a - b));
    if(bside< 0.0) return length(p-b);
    vec2 pointOnLine = (bside*a + aside*b)/pow(length(a-b),2.0);
    return length(p - pointOnLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one based on vector math; this solution will also work for higher dimensions *and* also report on the interection point (on the line segment).

```
def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2,px,py):
    a = np.array([[x1,y1]]).T
    b = np.array([[x2,y2]]).T
    x = np.array([[px,py]]).T
    tp = (np.dot(x.T, b) - np.dot(a.T, b)) / np.dot(b.T, b)
    tp = tp[0][0]
    tmp = x - (a + tp*b)
    d = np.sqrt(np.dot(tmp.T,tmp)[0][0])
    return d, a+tp*b

x1,y1=2.,2.
x2,y2=5.,5.
px,py=4.,1.

d, inters = dist(x1,y1, x2,y2, px,py)
print (d)
print (inters)
```

Result is

```
2.1213203435596424
[[2.5]
 [2.5]]
```

The math is explained here

https://brilliant.org/wiki/distance-between-point-and-line/

Answer (score 1):

Solution for dart and flutter:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
 class Utils {
   static double shortestDistance(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3){
      double px = p2.x - p1.x;
      double py = p2.y - p1.y;
      double temp = (px*px) + (py*py);
      double u = ((p3.x - p1.x)*px + (p3.y - p1.y)* py) /temp;
      if(u>1){
        u=1;
      }
      else if(u<0){
        u=0;
      }
      double x = p1.x + u*px;
      double y = p1.y + u*py;
      double dx = x - p3.x;
      double dy = y - p3.y;
      double dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
      return dist;
   }
}

class Point {
  double x;
  double y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Can you please tell me which equation you have used here? I had tried the shortest distance from line to a point but it didn't work for line segments.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** implementation of http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/source.c

```
    static func magnitude(p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let vector = CGPoint(x: p2.x - p1.x, y: p2.y - p1.y)
        return sqrt(pow(vector.x, 2) + pow(vector.y, 2))
    }

    /// http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
    /// http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/source.c
    static func pointDistanceToLine(point: CGPoint, lineStart: CGPoint, lineEnd: CGPoint) -> CGFloat? {

        let lineMag = magnitude(p1: lineEnd, p2: lineStart)
        let u = (((point.x - lineStart.x) * (lineEnd.x - lineStart.x)) +
                ((point.y - lineStart.y) * (lineEnd.y - lineStart.y))) /
                (lineMag * lineMag)

        if u < 0 || u > 1 {
            // closest point does not fall within the line segment
            return nil
        }

        let intersectionX = lineStart.x + u * (lineEnd.x - lineStart.x)
        let intersectionY = lineStart.y + u * (lineEnd.y - lineStart.y)

        return magnitude(p1: point, p2: CGPoint(x: intersectionX, y: intersectionY))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab direct Grumdrig implementation

```
function ans=distP2S(px,py,vx,vy,wx,wy)
% [px py vx vy wx wy]
  t=( (px-vx)*(wx-vx)+(py-vy)*(wy-vy) )/idist(vx,wx,vy,wy)^2;
  [idist(px,vx,py,vy) idist(px,vx+t*(wx-vx),py,vy+t*(wy-vy)) idist(px,wx,py,wy) ];
  ans(1+(t>0)+(t>1)); % <0 0<=t<=1 t>1     
 end

function d=idist(a,b,c,d)
 d=abs(a-b+1i*(c-d));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If its an infinite line, not a line segment, the simplest way is this (in ruby), where mx + b is the line and (x1, y1) is the known point

```
(y1 - mx1 - b).abs / Math.sqrt(m**2 + 1)
```

Comment: You haven't defined `mx1`, `b` or `m` and your solution is not for line segments.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and thought I'd add a Lua implementation. It assumes that points are given as tables {x=xVal, y=yVal} and the line or segment is given by a table containing two points (see example below):

```
function distance( P1, P2 )
    return math.sqrt((P1.x-P2.x)^2 + (P1.y-P2.y)^2)
end

-- Returns false if the point lies beyond the reaches of the segment
function distPointToSegment( line, P )
    if line[1].x == line[2].x and line[1].y == line[2].y then
        print("Error: Not a line!")
        return false
    end

    local d = distance( line[1], line[2] )

    local t = ((P.x - line[1].x)*(line[2].x - line[1].x) + (P.y - line[1].y)*(line[2].y - line[1].y))/(d^2)

    local projection = {}
    projection.x = line[1].x + t*(line[2].x-line[1].x)
    projection.y = line[1].y + t*(line[2].y-line[1].y)

    if t >= 0 and t <= 1 then   -- within line segment?
        return distance( projection, {x=P.x, y=P.y} )
    else
        return false
    end
end

-- Returns value even if point is further down the line (outside segment)
function distPointToLine( line, P )
    if line[1].x == line[2].x and line[1].y == line[2].y then
        print("Error: Not a line!")
        return false
    end

    local d = distance( line[1], line[2] )

    local t = ((P.x - line[1].x)*(line[2].x - line[1].x) + (P.y - line[1].y)*(line[2].y - line[1].y))/(d^2)

    local projection = {}
    projection.x = line[1].x + t*(line[2].x-line[1].x)
    projection.y = line[1].y + t*(line[2].y-line[1].y)

    return distance( projection, {x=P.x, y=P.y} )
end
```

Example usage:

```
local P1 = {x = 0, y = 0}
local P2 = {x = 10, y = 10}
local line = { P1, P2 }
local P3 = {x = 7, y = 15}
print(distPointToLine( line, P3 ))  -- prints 5.6568542494924
print(distPointToSegment( line, P3 )) -- prints false
```

Answer (score 0):

A little cleaner solution in JavaScript based on this [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line):
[image]

```
distToSegment: function (point, linePointA, linePointB){

    var x0 = point.X;
    var y0 = point.Y;

    var x1 = linePointA.X;
    var y1 = linePointA.Y;

    var x2 = linePointB.X;
    var y2 = linePointB.Y;

    var Dx = (x2 - x1);
    var Dy = (y2 - y1);

    var numerator = Math.abs(Dy*x0 - Dx*y0 - x1*y2 + x2*y1);
    var denominator = Math.sqrt(Dx*Dx + Dy*Dy);
    if (denominator == 0) {
        return this.dist2(point, linePointA);
    }

    return numerator/denominator;

}
```

Comment: Kudos for actually writing a formula down. However, this is the formula to calculate the distance to a line, not to a line segment. Picking (x0,y0)=(-10,0), (x1,y1)=(0,0), and (x2,y2)=(10,0) gives a distance of 0, while it should have been 10.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to do this in GLSL, but it's better to avoid all those conditionals if possible. Using clamp() avoids the two end-point cases:

```
// find closest point to P on line segment AB:
vec3 closest_point_on_line_segment(in vec3 P, in vec3 A, in vec3 B) {
    vec3 AP = P - A, AB = B - A;
    float l = dot(AB, AB);
    if (l <= 0.0000001) return A;    // A and B are practically the same
    return AP - AB*clamp(dot(AP, AB)/l, 0.0, 1.0);  // do the projection
}
```

If you can be sure that A and B are never very close to each other, this can be simplified to remove the if(). In fact, even if A and B *are* the same, my GPU still gives the right result with this condition-free version (but this is using pre-OpenGL 4.1 in which GLSL divide by zero is undefined):

```
// find closest point to P on line segment AB:
vec3 closest_point_on_line_segment(in vec3 P, in vec3 A, in vec3 B) {
    vec3 AP = P - A, AB = B - A;
    return AP - AB*clamp(dot(AP, AB)/dot(AB, AB), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

To compute the distance is trivial -- GLSL provides a distance() function which you can use on this closest point and P.

Inspired by [Iñigo Quilez's code for a capsule distance function](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853926/407108), except in Visual Basic. Makes it usable as a User Defined Function in Microsoft Excel and VBA/macros.

The function returns the closest distance from point (x,y) to the segment defined by (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

```
Function DistanceToSegment(x As Double, y As Double, x1 As Double, y1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double)

  Dim A As Double
  A = x - x1
  Dim B As Double
  B = y - y1
  Dim C  As Double
  C = x2 - x1
  Dim D As Double
  D = y2 - y1

  Dim dot As Double
  dot = A * C + B * D
  Dim len_sq As Double
  len_sq = C * C + D * D
  Dim param As Double
  param = -1

  If (len_sq <> 0) Then
      param = dot / len_sq
  End If

  Dim xx As Double
  Dim yy As Double

  If (param < 0) Then
    xx = x1
    yy = y1
  ElseIf (param > 1) Then
    xx = x2
    yy = y2
  Else
    xx = x1 + param * C
    yy = y1 + param * D
  End If

  Dim dx As Double
  dx = x - xx
  Dim dy As Double
  dy = y - yy

  DistanceToSegment = Math.Sqr(dx * dx + dy * dy)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lua:**
Finds minimum distance between a line segment(not the whole line) and a point

```
function solveLinearEquation(A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2)
--it is the implitaion of a method of solving linear equations in x and y
  local f1 = B1*C2 -B2*C1
  local f2 = A2*C1-A1*C2
  local f3 = A1*B2 -A2*B1
  return {x= f1/f3, y= f2/f3}
end


function pointLiesOnLine(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2)
  local dx1 = x-x1
  local  dy1 = y-y1
  local dx2 = x-x2
  local  dy2 = y-y2
  local crossProduct = dy1*dx2 -dx1*dy2

if crossProduct ~= 0  then  return  false
else
  if ((x1>=x) and (x>=x2)) or ((x2>=x) and (x>=x1)) then
    if ((y1>=y) and (y>=y2)) or ((y2>=y) and (y>=y1)) then
      return true
    else return false end
  else  return false end
end
end


function dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
  local dx = x1-x2
  local dy = y1-y2
  return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy* dy)
 end


function findMinDistBetnPointAndLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
-- finds the min  distance between (x3,y3) and line (x1,y2)--(x2,y2)
   local A2,B2,C2,A1,B1,C1
   local dx = y2-y1
   local dy = x2-x1
   if dx == 0 then A2=1 B2=0 C2=-x3 A1=0 B1=1 C1=-y1 
   elseif dy == 0 then A2=0 B2=1 C2=-y3 A1=1 B1=0 C1=-x1
   else
      local m1 = dy/dx
      local m2 = -1/m1
      A2=m2 B2=-1 C2=y3-m2*x3 A1=m1 B1=-1 C1=y1-m1*x1
   end
 local intsecPoint= solveLinearEquation(A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2)
if pointLiesOnLine(intsecPoint.x, intsecPoint.y,x1,y1,x2,y2) then
   return dist(intsecPoint.x, intsecPoint.y, x3,y3)
 else
   return math.min(dist(x3,y3,x1,y1),dist(x3,y3,x2,y2))
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501725/2624876)'s JavaScript solution.
It's mainly just formatted nicer, with longer function names, and of course shorter function syntax because it's in ES6 + CoffeeScript.

### JavaScript version (ES6)

```
distanceSquared = (v, w)=> Math.pow(v.x - w.x, 2) + Math.pow(v.y - w.y, 2);
distance = (v, w)=> Math.sqrt(distanceSquared(v, w));

distanceToLineSegmentSquared = (p, v, w)=> {
    l2 = distanceSquared(v, w);
    if (l2 === 0) {
        return distanceSquared(p, v);
    }
    t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
    t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t));
    return distanceSquared(p, {
        x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x),
        y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)
    });
}
distanceToLineSegment = (p, v, w)=> {
    return Math.sqrt(distanceToLineSegmentSquared(p, v));
}
```

### CoffeeScript version

```
distanceSquared = (v, w)-> (v.x - w.x) ** 2 + (v.y - w.y) ** 2
distance = (v, w)-> Math.sqrt(distanceSquared(v, w))

distanceToLineSegmentSquared = (p, v, w)->
    l2 = distanceSquared(v, w)
    return distanceSquared(p, v) if l2 is 0
    t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2
    t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t))
    distanceSquared(p, {
        x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x)
        y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)
    })

distanceToLineSegment = (p, v, w)->
    Math.sqrt(distanceToLineSegmentSquared(p, v, w))
```

Comment: In the JS version, distance() is redundant, no?

Comment: Yeah, in both versions it's unused. Feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

## in R

```
     #distance beetween segment ab and point c in 2D space
getDistance_ort_2 <- function(a, b, c){
  #go to complex numbers
  A<-c(a[1]+1i*a[2],b[1]+1i*b[2])
  q=c[1]+1i*c[2]
  
  #function to get coefficients of line (ab)
  getAlphaBeta <- function(A)
  { a<-Re(A[2])-Re(A[1])
    b<-Im(A[2])-Im(A[1])
    ab<-as.numeric()
    ab[1] <- -Re(A[1])*b/a+Im(A[1])
    ab[2] <-b/a
    if(Im(A[1])==Im(A[2])) ab<- c(Im(A[1]),0)
    if(Re(A[1])==Re(A[2])) ab <- NA
    return(ab)
  }
  
  #function to get coefficients of line ortogonal to line (ab) which goes through point q
  getAlphaBeta_ort<-function(A,q)
  { ab <- getAlphaBeta(A) 
  coef<-c(Re(q)/ab[2]+Im(q),-1/ab[2])
  if(Re(A[1])==Re(A[2])) coef<-c(Im(q),0)
  return(coef)
  }
  
  #function to get coordinates of interception point 
  #between line (ab) and its ortogonal which goes through point q
  getIntersection_ort <- function(A, q){
    A.ab <- getAlphaBeta(A)
    q.ab <- getAlphaBeta_ort(A,q)
    if (!is.na(A.ab[1])&A.ab[2]==0) {
      x<-Re(q)
      y<-Im(A[1])}
    if (is.na(A.ab[1])) {
      x<-Re(A[1])
      y<-Im(q)
    } 
    if (!is.na(A.ab[1])&A.ab[2]!=0) {
      x <- (q.ab[1] - A.ab[1])/(A.ab[2] - q.ab[2])
      y <- q.ab[1] + q.ab[2]*x}
    xy <- x + 1i*y  
    return(xy)
  }
  
  intersect<-getIntersection_ort(A,q)
  if ((Mod(A[1]-intersect)+Mod(A[2]-intersect))>Mod(A[1]-A[2])) {dist<-min(Mod(A[1]-q),Mod(A[2]-q))
  } else dist<-Mod(q-intersect)
  return(dist)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript using Geometry:

```
var a = { x:20, y:20};//start segment    
var b = { x:40, y:30};//end segment   
var c = { x:37, y:14};//point   

// magnitude from a to c    
var ac = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( a.x - c.x ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( a.y - c.y ), 2) );    
// magnitude from b to c   
var bc = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( b.x - c.x ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( b.y - c.y ), 2 ) );    
// magnitude from a to b (base)     
var ab = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( a.x - b.x ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( a.y - b.y ), 2 ) );    
 // perimeter of triangle     
var p = ac + bc + ab;    
 // area of the triangle    
var area = Math.sqrt( p/2 * ( p/2 - ac) * ( p/2 - bc ) * ( p/2 - ab ) );    
 // height of the triangle = distance    
var h = ( area * 2 ) / ab;    
console.log ("height: " + h);
```

Comment: nice idea, but height will be distance to line, in some cases distance to segment = distance to segment's start or end.

Answer (score 0):

Eigen C++ Version for 3D line segment and point

```
// Return minimum distance between line segment: head--->tail and point
double MinimumDistance(Eigen::Vector3d head, Eigen::Vector3d tail,Eigen::Vector3d point)
{
    double l2 = std::pow((head - tail).norm(),2);
    if(l2 ==0.0) return (head - point).norm();// head == tail case

    // Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as head + t (tail - point).
    // We find projection of point onto the line.
    // It falls where t = [(point-head) . (tail-head)] / |tail-head|^2
    // We clamp t from [0,1] to handle points outside the segment head--->tail.

    double t = max(0,min(1,(point-head).dot(tail-head)/l2));
    Eigen::Vector3d projection = head + t*(tail-head);

    return (point - projection).norm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self contained Delphi / Pascal version of the function based on Joshua's answer up above. Uses TPoint for VCL screen graphics, but should be easy to adjust as needed.

```
function DistancePtToSegment( pt, pt1, pt2: TPoint): double;
var
   a, b, c, d: double;
   len_sq: double;
   param: double;
   xx, yy: double;
   dx, dy: double;
begin
   a := pt.x - pt1.x;
   b := pt.y - pt1.y;
   c := pt2.x - pt1.x;
   d := pt2.y - pt1.y;

   len_sq := (c * c) + (d * d);
   param := -1;

   if (len_sq <> 0) then
   begin
      param := ((a * c) + (b * d)) / len_sq;
   end;

   if param < 0 then
   begin
      xx := pt1.x;
      yy := pt1.y;
   end
   else if param > 1 then
   begin
      xx := pt2.x;
      yy := pt2.y;
   end
   else begin
      xx := pt1.x + param * c;
      yy := pt1.y + param * d;
   end;

   dx := pt.x - xx;
   dy := pt.y - yy;
   result := sqrt( (dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL implementation for HSQLDB:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dist_to_segment(px double, py double, vx double, vy double, wx double, wy double)
  RETURNS double
BEGIN atomic
   declare l2 double;
   declare t double;
   declare nx double;
   declare ny double;
   set l2 =(vx - wx)*(vx - wx) + (vy - wy)*(vy - wy);
   IF l2 = 0 THEN
     RETURN sqrt((vx - px)*(vx - px) + (vy - py)*(vy - py));
   ELSE
     set t = ((px - vx) * (wx - vx) + (py - vy) * (wy - vy)) / l2;
     set t = GREATEST(0, LEAST(1, t));
     set nx=vx + t * (wx - vx);
     set ny=vy + t * (wy - vy);
     RETURN sqrt((nx - px)*(nx - px) + (ny - py)*(ny - py));
   END IF;
END;
```

And implementation for Postgres:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dist_to_segment(px numeric, py numeric, vx numeric, vy numeric, wx numeric, wy numeric)
  RETURNS numeric
AS $$
   declare l2 numeric;
   declare t numeric;
   declare nx numeric;
   declare ny numeric;
BEGIN 
   l2 := (vx - wx)*(vx - wx) + (vy - wy)*(vy - wy);
   IF l2 = 0 THEN
     RETURN sqrt((vx - px)*(vx - px) + (vy - py)*(vy - py));
   ELSE
     t := ((px - vx) * (wx - vx) + (py - vy) * (wy - vy)) / l2;
     t := GREATEST(0, LEAST(1, t));
     nx := vx + t * (wx - vx);
     ny := vy + t * (wy - vy);
     RETURN sqrt((nx - px)*(nx - px) + (ny - py)*(ny - py));
   END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lua solution

```
-- distance from point (px, py) to line segment (x1, y1, x2, y2)
function distPointToLine(px,py,x1,y1,x2,y2) -- point, start and end of the segment
    local dx,dy = x2-x1,y2-y1
    local length = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    dx,dy = dx/length,dy/length -- normalization
    local p = dx*(px-x1)+dy*(py-y1)
    if p < 0 then
        dx,dy = px-x1,py-y1
        return math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy), x1, y1 -- distance, nearest point
    elseif p > length then
        dx,dy = px-x2,py-y2
        return math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy), x2, y2 -- distance, nearest point
    end
    return math.abs(dy*(px-x1)-dx*(py-y1)), x1+dx*p, y1+dy*p -- distance, nearest point
end
```

For polyline (line with more than two segments):

```
-- if the (poly-)line has several segments, just iterate through all of them:
function nearest_sector_in_line (x, y, line)
    local x1, y1, x2, y2, min_dist
    local ax,ay = line[1], line[2]
    for j = 3, #line-1, 2 do
        local bx,by = line[j], line[j+1]
        local dist = distPointToLine(x,y,ax,ay,bx,by)
        if not min_dist or dist < min_dist then
            min_dist = dist
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = ax,ay,bx,by
        end
        ax, ay = bx, by
    end
    return x1, y1, x2, y2
end
```

Example:

```
-- call it:
local x1, y1, x2, y2 = nearest_sector_in_line (7, 4, {0,0, 10,0, 10,10, 0,10})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the library for PHP [geo-math-php](https://github.com/rkondratuk/geo-math-php)

```php
composer require rkondratuk/geo-math-php:^1
```

Example:

```php
<?php

use PhpGeoMath\Model\GeoSegment;
use PhpGeoMath\Model\Polar3dPoint;

$polarPoint1 = new Polar3dPoint(
    40.758742779050706, -73.97855507715238, Polar3dPoint::EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS
);

$polarPoint2 = new Polar3dPoint(
    40.74843388072615, -73.98566565776102, Polar3dPoint::EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS
);

$polarPoint3 = new Polar3dPoint(
    40.74919365249446, -73.98133456388013, Polar3dPoint::EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS
);

$arcSegment = new GeoSegment($polarPoint1, $polarPoint2);
$nearestPolarPoint = $arcSegment->calcNearestPoint($polarPoint3);

// Shortest distance from point-3 to segment(point-1, point-2)
$geoDistance = $nearestPolarPoint->calcGeoDistanceToPoint($polarPoint3);
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed a Godot (GDscript) implementation of this so I wrote one based on [grumdrig's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment/1501725#1501725) accepted answer:

```
func minimum_distance(v: Vector2, w: Vector2, p: Vector2):
    # Return minimum distance between line segment vw and point p
    var l2: float = (v - w).length_squared()  # i.e. |w-v|^2 -  avoid a sqrt
    if l2 == 0.0:
        return p.distance_to(v) # v == w case

    # Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as v + t (w - v).
    # We find projection of point p onto the line.
    # It falls where t = [(p-v) . (w-v)] / |w-v|^2
    # We clamp t from [0,1] to handle points outside the segment vw.
    var t: float = max(0, min(1, (p - v).dot(w - v) / l2))
    var projection: Vector2 = v + t * (w - v)  # Projection falls on the segment
    
    return p.distance_to(projection)
```